# update widget with set state function

Tags: flutter

I need some clarifications on `setState()` function.
I divided the questions to 3, but they're all about `setState()`.

1. When calling `setState` does all the widget on the app or in the
   context(?) are re-rendered / updated?
2. What is the importantance of the code inside the `setState(() {/* MY
   CODE  */});` against `/* myCode;*/ setState(() {});`
3. In case I am updating some variables inside the `setState` function
   like:  `setState(() { myText='dfg';})` and this variable
   updates a widget, `Text(myText)`, how does `setState` will know to update
   the Text widget?

**For example, in the following classic code:**

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample Code'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('You have pressed the button $_count times.'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          height: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() {
          _count++;
        }),
        tooltip: 'Increment Counter',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
}
```

the setState() is called in the bottomNavigationBar widget (so this widget is marked as dirty), so why we can see the update in the Text widget that relate to child...body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- when you call the `setState()` method only that widget get re-build.

- i don't want to make things complicated but there is one exception to this rule, and that when using a **Lifiting state up** technique which will lead to multiple widgets being re-drawn every time the Consumer widget do a callback to the ancestor for re-building state. i will show a diagram below which i hope it make it clearer, but you don't need to worry about it if it seems complicated because you wouldn't be using that technique anyway as there are others that are way simpler and easier.

[image]

2- there is no difference it's just more meaningful to put the code that changes inside the `setState()` method indicating these are variables that change.

3- when you call `setState()` like in your example like this
`setState(() => _count++);` not the widget that the `setState` method get called in will be marked as dirty rather than the widgets that depend on that state(here the state is the `_count` variable), so on the next call to `build` method the framework see the `Text` widget that uses the `_counter` variable as dirty thus re-draw it, the diagram below show your widget tree and explain how it's done
[image]

Comment: I edited to question + your answer to Question #3, is not clear. what's the difference between setState() to widget and setState() that call the build

Comment: i updated the answer, i hope it cleared some confusion.

Comment: ok! so with the "setState(() => _count++)" every widget that use _count variable will be mark as dirty? i.e if I use _count++ outside the setState function - no widget will mark as dirty ? (if yes, using empty setState  ```setState((){})``` is useless ?

Comment: No because the framework doesn't look at what is inside the `setState( () { // code }) ` method rather it look at what changed when the `setState` method got triggered and mark widgets dirty that used that variable that got changed when `setState` was triggered.

Comment: so, what change where ? what is the "scope" that the framework look for charges? the entire app? the specific current function?

Comment: as stated in the documentation:



Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build **for this State object**, it look just inside the State object not the entire app.

Comment: so when setState is fire, the framework look at what variables/data changed that might influence widgets display and mark all of those widgets as dirty?

Comment: exactly, just a little correction to your statement will be:  look at what variables/data changed **inside the State object**.

Comment: nice link for a good article: https://medium.com/flutterpub/statefulwidgets-key-state-8ad83ac2e54f